# How to set State in NativeAppEventEmitter?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm retrieving some data from BLE but I'm not able to set it to a state in order to display it on to a component.I use the register notification function to send a request and I'm using the NativeAppEventEmitter to retrieve the data it returns.I use that data , work on it and then I'm trying to set it to a state inorder to load it onto a component.

````
BleHelper.registerNotification(peripheral.id, xxxx, xxxx, this._onCharValueUpdate)
                .then(handle => {
                      NativeAppEventEmitter.addListener('BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic', function(data){ 
                        console.log(data.value);
                       // let x = new Uint8Array([-2])
                        let buffer = Buffer.from([254]);
                        let exponent = buffer.readInt8(0);
                        console.log("before");

                        let temp= data.value[3] << (16)| data.value[2]<<(8)|data.value[1];

                        console.log("after");
                        console.log(temp*(Math.pow(10,exponent)));
                       let temperature = temp*(Math.pow(10,exponent));

                       this.setState({
                        temperature:temperature
                    });                    });


                    this.notifyHandle = handle;
                    this.forceUpdate();
                }
                )
                .catch(err => {
                    console.warn(err)
                    //ErrorRegistry.putError('GATT Register Notification', err);
                });
        } ```
````

Comment: Could you add a little more details on what happens when you call `setState()` ?

Comment: this.setState is not a function. (In 'this.setState({
               temperature: temperature
            })', 'this.setState' is undefined)
this is the error I get when setstate is called

Comment: Is this whole code block being executed inside a lifecycle method? Please provide a little more context where in your script you placed it.

Comment: No its inside a lifecycle method but it is inside another method which sends a data request and this block probably acts as a listener and fetches the data it returns

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to simulate the context situation? That would help a lot.

Comment: I've made changes to the question it should help

Comment: I still don't see any trace of an enclosing React Component. You can only find `this.setSate()` in the context of a React Component.